# Redis queue in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

I have two folders with identical sites. One folder: `beta`, the second: the main site.

I added my site to the `beta` for testing, notifications worked fine there (added to the queue, and then sent an email). When I moved the same site to the main folder, the notifications stopped being added to the queue, I'm using redis so I tried changing the prefix and databases (`0` and `1` to `2` and `3`) to store.

If I go to redis using the command line, all the databases are there so the cache works stably, but notifications are not added to the queue at all. Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

The queue always works on `beta`, I completely reinstalled all the files. Perhaps I forgot to change something in some config?

I am not using `supervisord` at the moment, I also use different `REDIS_QUEUE` values.

my notification:

```
class SendMagicLinkNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue {
    use Queueable;

    public $tries = 3;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable) {

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting('Hi,...) //some code
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

my .env:

```
...
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DB=2 //0 in beta
REDIS_CACHE_DB=3 //1 in beta
REDIS_QUEUE=production
REDIS_PREFIX=mysite_production_database
...
```

my config/database.php:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: My brain exploded when I read your giant paragraph without dots (`.`) and commas (`,`) and new lines, so please, next time, take the needed time and use new lines, dots and commas...

Comment: We cannot help you at all if you do not share any code or config. Your issue is like reading about something abstract or relative, without facts it is impossible to say something, less help... What queue config are you using in `beta` and in the main site? Do you have code that understands if it is in `beta` or the other folder and does something diffrent? How are you moving these files to main folder? Are you restarting workers?

Comment: I just downloaded the same site files from git and created the same configs

Comment: You still need to share something, we can't help you without data...

Comment: I edited the post and added the code to it

Comment: The situation has changed: the site puts tasks in the queue, but when you run the php artisan queue:listen, it says that the queue is empty